# Make Samba on Ubuntu 18.04 work with Windows clients which require digitally signed communications

Tags: 18.04, windows-7, samba

Due to a recent change of security policies where I work, users' Windows 7 PCs are now configured with `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always)` enabled, and no longer able to access Samba share at my Ubuntu 18.04 server. I've tried several combinations of `server signing`, `client signing` and `smb encrypt` in smb.conf and still cannot make it work, and I can't find a HOWTO/manual about this.

Currently smb.conf includes

```
server signing = mandatory
client signing = mandatory
smb encrypt = required
```

With or without these three lines lead to same results (`sudo service smbd restart` in between). And the Samba server is not in AD domain (`server role = standalone server`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

(EDIT - log and conf files added)

I stopped smbd service, deleted all existing log files, started smbd service, tried to connect from Windows, again stopped smbd service, and then grabbed the log files. I did this procedure twice, with the first time the aforementioned Windows policy was set, and the second time it wasn't (and therefore this time Windows successfully connected to Samba).

I couldn't find a guide about what value log level should be set to, so I've set it to 10, which produced enormous logs. They are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kN8iWCj4NmL0GSOsTNy8yjRO1RTZhG1J), alongside my smb.conf, which has these additional lines compared to default Ubuntu smb.conf:

```
security = user
unix extensions = no
log level = 10
[homes]
browseable = no
read only = no
create mask = 0764
directory mask = 2775
valid users = %S
guest ok = no
wide links = yes
```

(I've removed aforementioned signing/encrypt lines after last time I post since they're of no help.)

(Later edited) If log level 10 is too overwhelming, level 5 logs are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gjDdjm9P0aKH9h8uzTz1-fEAbB1JpiJG).

As for the client side [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n51S8.jpg)... it's problematic because we use Traditional Chinese version of Windows here. After some googling, I guess the equivalent message in English version of Windows would be "The account is not authorized to log in from this station." And I should have clarified that with successful connections, username/password dialog pops up first, in which I input those of my Ubuntu user, and they succeed. While with failed ones, there's no dialog, solely the message.

Comment: Any useful errors in the samba log? You should be able to set the [log level](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_the_Samba_Log_Level) which might provide us with useful clues to help you resolve this issue. [edit]ing new info into your post will also bump it so that more eyes see it and any new information may help uncover a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Got help from [Samba mailing list](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2018-October/219056.html).

Commenting out the default `map to guest = bad user` line works.

Comment: Wow, would never have tried that. +1

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what error messages do you get?  To help prompt my brain.

Encrypt is NOT of course the same as signing. Encrypt is the whole message block. So pretty sure you do not want that option on.

Digital Signature (if I remember right) has been at various time in SMB history -- either simple session ID key matches or an hash of each message based on session key (ID plus anti-tamper proof) at end instead of ancient simple CRC type thing.

---

Even more basic is make sure Ubuntu is negotiating for protocols up to SMBv2 and SMBv3. I don't think SMBv1 knows what to do with Digital Signatures or full SMB encryption.

Yet not too many version back SMBv1 was still the default assumption for easing connections to Windows machines. I guess that was kept on theory that -- in absolute numbers of such installations - most places did not have expertise in both Linux and Windows. And of course places that did have people with both expertise would automatic realize the "Expert" settings required.

Again I don't know what the nature of the errors messages you get -- so I can't rule out anything along line of needing negotiation for use of SMBv2/SMBv3 in place of SMBv1 at this point.

In any case I am pretty sure Digital Signature policy alone (SMBv2 feature) leaves main message in plain text for quicker processing and inspection by various network devices (less client or server overhead too).  Encrypted SMB as part of protocol is fairly recent. Not easily trigger behavior for Window 7 though probably added as an available feature before end of Windows 7 support. Released with SMBv3 I think during Windows 8.1 release.