# Windows clients unable to connect to print server using samba?

Tags: server, printing, samba, cups-lpd

I stood up a print server using samba and cups. When I connect to this printer using a macOS machine or a Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I have no trouble printing.
When I try to add the printer on a Windows client, it always fails, saying "That did not work..".

If I attempt to add the printer through the network by visiting \svr-printerserver\ in File Explorer, I see the printer. However if I double click to connect, it fails. I've located logs for this method on the print server in /var/log/samba/log.[devicename], where devicename is my windows 10 computer's hostname:

```
[2022/06/28 16:22:41.570502,  0] ../../auth/gensec/gensec.c:306(gensec_verify_features)
Did not manage to negotiate mandatory feature SIGN
[2022/06/28 16:22:45.657007,  0] ../../auth/gensec/gensec.c:306(gensec_verify_features)
Did not manage to negotiate mandatory feature SIGN
[2022/06/28 16:22:45.750694,  0] ../../auth/gensec/gensec.c:306(gensec_verify_features)
Did not manage to negotiate mandatory feature SIGN
[2022/06/28 16:22:59.368689,  0] ../../auth/gensec/gensec.c:306(gensec_verify_features)
Did not manage to negotiate mandatory feature SIGN
```

I've search `Did not manage to negotiate mandatory feature SIGN` extensively with a few promising leads that ended up not working. One suggestion was to add `server signing = auto` and `client signing = auto` to `/etc/samba/smb.cnf`. This had no noticeable change.

I'm at odds and ends.

Comment: This may be a Windows issue. Did you read this: https://www.tomshardware.com/news/printnightmare-fix-breaks-network-printing#xenforo-comments-3724645 ?

Comment: Did you try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1088435/149708 (commenting out the `map to guest = bad user` line)?

Comment: Did you restart the samba server after you edited `/etc/samba/smb.conf`? Most linux servers don't monitor their config files to detect changes - they use Signals and/or server restarts to apply updated configurations.

Comment: @Jos , I don't think this pertains to my situation but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jos , having `map to guest - bad user` allows for any machine to access the share, which I want. Commenting this line out prompted a password when trying to access the share, which I do not want.

@waltinator , Yes I restart the service after any change to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`